# DOM implementation in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there an implementation or emulation of the DOM which is purely javascript?

- There is env.js, but that requires Rhino.
- There's jsdom, but that requires Node.

Is there a solution that works in most any javascript interpreter, such as v8, without being tied to any particular interpreter or engine?  That is, is there any DOM implementation in JS that without any set up or shims can be dropped into a javascript interpreter and just run?

Comment: Could you explain why you need this?

Comment: It's to test javascript code.

Comment: I am looking for something similar, here is the reason for me: I want to run it in v8 js engine (controlled by golang bindings to v8), but not necessarily in node.

Comment: @JPuge Questions like this always turn out to be retarded as the time goes on. The reasons may include: Using DOM in web workers, using DOM in custom native application that runs HTML and Javascript, using javascript to validate some HTML files...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the ones you have listed, I have heard good things about [dom.js](https://github.com/andreasgal/dom.js). It requires limited ES6 features such as `const`, `WeakMap`, and `Proxy`, so it will work in V8 and SpiderMonkey (Rhino) but not JavaScriptCore, Chakra, or others.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess at exactly what you're trying to do, here, but I'll take a stab at it, just to keep the conversation going:

- If you're trying to manipulate a DOM from within a browser, can't you just use [Jquery](http://jquery.org/)?
- If you're trying to get a "headless browser", I'd check out [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/).

I guess it's hard to imagine how you'd even run Javascript code without a browser, or Rhino, or Node, or PhantomJS, or some other JS interpreter environment...

Comment: If you're trying to manipulate a DOM from within a browser, can't you just use [the DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM)?

Comment: I realize this is not the same... however for what he's asking for teaching people *how to use* the DOM api and not abstracting a layer on top of it would be best.

Comment: Actually, it's to abstract out the DOM away from browsers and their trappings to test code.