# How to parse HTML (and re-generate) with a standalone v8 interpreter?

Tags: javascript, html-parsing, v8

I want to parse an html file/string into a DOM/tree structure. 
And preferably later to modify the tree and regenerate the marked up HTML.

This has to be in pure javascript from a standalone v8 interpreter.

jQuery is an obvious choice but it seems to be browser only
There is some info on how to do this in node.js
e.g. [Can I use jQuery with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js)

THis answer seems to rule out jsdom on v8
[How to load a nodejs module in PyV8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833756/how-to-load-a-nodejs-module-in-pyv8)

Has anyone got a working combination with standalone v8 ?

I am a js newbie but i am already parsing/re-generating js code using esprima/escodegen on v8 which works very nicely....

Comment: According to this post you could use dom.js: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9726383/1427115